# Types of property xxx are incompatible, but it is - ts(2322)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a problem with TypeScript that say my property isn't compatible, but I think it is

- Types of property 'size' are incompatible.
- Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"s" | "m" | "l" | "xl" | undefined'.ts(2322)

How can I fix it?

#### ./src/components/App

```
function App() {
  const params = {
    label: 'Select',
    placeholder: 'Placeholder',
    isRequired: true,
    offset: { X: '0', Y: '100%' },
    zIndex: 10,
    size: 's',
    classes: ['class1', 'class2', 'class3', 'class4', 'class5'],
  };

  return <SelectMenu params={params} />;
}
```

#### ./src/components/SelectMenu

```
function SelectMenu({
  params: {
    label,
    placeholder,
    isRequired = false,
    offset = { X: '0', Y: '100%' },
    zIndex = 0,
    size = 'm',
    classes,
  },
}: {
  params: {
    label?: string;
    placeholder?: string;
    isRequired?: boolean;
    offset?: { X: string; Y: string };
    zIndex?: number;
    size?: 's' | 'm' | 'l' | 'xl';
    classes?: string | string[];
  };
})
```

I want it to work like that. Is this possible?

```
  const params = {
    label: 'Select',
    placeholder: 'Placeholder',
    isRequired: true,
    offset: { X: '0', Y: '100%' },
    zIndex: 10,
    size: 's',
    classes: ['class1', 'class2', 'class3', 'class4', 'class5'],
  };

  return <SelectMenu {...params} />;
```

```
type Params = {
  label?: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  isRequired?: boolean;
  offset?: { X: string; Y: string };
  zIndex?: number;
  size?: 's' | 'm' | 'l' | 'xl';
  classes?: string | string[];
};

function SelectMenu({
  label,
  placeholder,
  isRequired = false,
  offset = { X: '0', Y: '100%' },
  zIndex = 0,
  size = 'm',
  classes,
}: Params)
```

Comment: Type string is *any* string, your type is requiring one of the specified strings. If this is MUI, have a look at the union types they use behind the scenes, or just define your own union of valid strings.

Comment: Hi, yes i want it to be one of the specified strings and not a simple string

Comment: Modify your title. It must be related to the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the type of `params` after you declare it, you can see has literal types widened and is:

```
const params: {
    label: string;
    placeholder: string;
    isRequired: boolean;
    offset: {
        X: string;
        Y: string;
    };
    zIndex: number;
    size: string;
    classes: string[];
}
```

So you can either case individual fields to their literal type `size: 'm' as 'm'` or can add `as const` to the object:

```
  const params = {
    label: 'Select',
    placeholder: 'Placeholder',
    isRequired: true,
    offset: { X: '0', Y: '100%' },
    zIndex: 10,
    size: 's',
    classes: ['class1', 'class2', 'class3', 'class4', 'class5'],
  } as const;
```

which gives types

```
const params: {
    readonly label: "Select";
    readonly placeholder: "Placeholder";
    readonly isRequired: true;
    readonly offset: {
        readonly X: "0";
        readonly Y: "100%";
    };
    readonly zIndex: 10;
    readonly size: "s";
    readonly classes: readonly [...];
}
```

Or if you don't want to do that, if you create `params` inline in the component render, it should accept it:

```
<SelectMenu params={{
    label: 'Select',
    placeholder: 'Placeholder',
    isRequired: true,
    offset: { X: '0', Y: '100%' },
    zIndex: 10,
    size: 's',
    classes: ['class1', 'class2', 'class3', 'class4', 'class5'],
  }} />
```

Comment: Look my edit, I specified my question :)

Comment: At that point it's up to the user

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a [`const` assertion](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-4-rc/#const-assertions) (`as const`):

```
const params = {
    label: 'Select',
    placeholder: 'Placeholder',
    isRequired: true,
    offset: { X: '0', Y: '100%' },
    zIndex: 10,
    size: 's',
    classes: ['class1', 'class2', 'class3', 'class4', 'class5'],
} as const;
```

But note it will affect the resulting type quite a bit, as stated in the docs:

> When declaring a mutable variable or property, TypeScript often widens values to make sure that we can assign things later on without writing an explicit type.
>
> [...]
>
> To solve this, TypeScript 3.4 introduces a new construct for literal values called `const` assertions. Its syntax is a type assertion with `const` in place of the type name (e.g. `123 as const`). When we construct new literal expressions with `const` assertions, we can signal to the language that
>
> - no literal types in that expression should be widened (e.g. no going from "hello" to string)
> - object literals get readonly properties
> - array literals become readonly tuples

Or [`satiesfies`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator):

```
import type { Params } from "../SelectMenu";

const params = {
    label: 'Select',
    placeholder: 'Placeholder',
    isRequired: true,
    offset: { X: '0', Y: '100%' },
    zIndex: 10,
    size: 's',
    classes: ['class1', 'class2', 'class3', 'class4', 'class5'],
} satisfies Params;
```

Which doesn't affect the resulting type as much (probably closest to what you want, IMO):

> TypeScript developers are often faced with a dilemma: we want to ensure that some expression matches some type, but also want to keep the most specific type of that expression for inference purposes.
>
> [...]
>
> The new `satisfies` operator lets us validate that the type of an expression matches some type, without changing the resulting type of that expression.

Here you can see the difference between using both:

```
declare const paramsAsConst: {
    readonly label: "Select";
    readonly placeholder: "Placeholder";
    readonly isRequired: true;
    readonly offset: {
        readonly X: "0";
        readonly Y: "100%";
    };
    readonly zIndex: 10;
    readonly size: "s";
    readonly classes: readonly ["class1", "class2", "class3", "class4", "class5"];
};

declare const paramsSatisfies: {
    label: string;
    placeholder: string;
    isRequired: true;
    offset: {
        X: string;
        Y: string;
    };
    zIndex: number;
    size: "s";
    classes: string[];
};
```

Comment: Look my edit, I specified my question :)

Comment: @FlorianSIMUNEK To get what you want (avoid manually specifying or narrowing down the type) you would need to declare `size` as `string` instead. I recommend using `satisfies` instead.

Comment: The problem is : I don't want the params constant to be typed, I juste want the SelectMenu component to be, because my SelectMenu will be a npm package, and I don't want the user to have to write the type themself

Comment: They can always use `as const` to avoid using the type. In any case, if you really want to avoid any kind of issue with that, type `size` as `string`.